# Objective-c: Error when setting value to class object in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

My NSMutableArray stores class objects. Here is the class (I initialized all the variables in .m):

```
@interface positionInfor : NSObject
{
  @public
  double xPos;
  double yPos;
  double degree;
  int    accuracy;
  BOOL   flag;
}
@end
```

When I want to set a new value for flag variable by using setValue function:

```
//avgDataTwo is NSMutable array stores all the class objects.
[[avgDataTwo objectAtIndex:i+1]setValue:@"TRUE" forKey:@"flag"];
```

It gives me this error :

```
 -[__NSCFConstantString charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1000086a8
```

I am sure all my data is in the array ((i+1) is equal to 2, when the error occurs):

[image]

Thanks !!!

Comment: Try [[avgDataTwo objectAtIndex:i+1]setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"flag"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a string value for the key. You do need to pass an object, but you should pass an NSValue / NSNumber with a boolean value. There's the shortcut:

```
[[avgDataTwo objectAtIndex:i+1]setValue:@YES forKey:@"flag"];
```

Or the more verbose way:

```
[[avgDataTwo objectAtIndex:i+1]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"flag"];
```

Comment: Rather than `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` you can use a literal: `@(YES)`

Comment: @BergQuester or even `@YES`, which is what I do in the first line of code there. I added the `numberWithBool:` option to try and clear up  some of the magic.

Comment: Derp, sorry, so you did.